# Swift pushViewController causing app crash

Tags: ios, swift, segue, pushviewcontroller

I am new to swift development here, trying to change the presentation style for iOS 13 to use the push kind of style. The original source uses the storyboard to set the presentation style for viewcontrollers but there is one part that they override it with

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
```

I managed to make it transition with pushViewController but the app crashes right after it, may I know what is the problem here?
This is the full function

```
        override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let selectedIndex:Int? = menuTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row


    if (selectedIndex! == 0 || selectedIndex! == 1){
        let submitViewController: SubmitViewController = segue.destination as! SubmitViewController

        if (selectedIndex! == 0){
            submitViewController.currency = Constant.CURRENCY_MYR
        }else{
            submitViewController.currency = Constant.CURRENCY_SGD
        }
    }else if (selectedIndex! == MENU_ACCOUNT_STATISTIC_INDEX){

        let target: SearchResultViewController = segue.destination as! SearchResultViewController


        target.toolbarOption = SearchResultViewToolBarOption.TOOLBAR_SMS
        target.resultContent = self.resultContent

        self.navigationController!.pushViewController(target, animated: true)



    }
```

This is the error log that I get

```
    2020-04-04 14:50:24.227072+0800 vboss[38120:1974490] *** Terminating app due to uncaught          exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller <vboss.MenuViewController: 0x7fd906087e00>.'
```

Comment: You can't do a push or any other type of navigation if a segue is already in progress. If you really want different presentation styles for different cell selections, you are going to have to define different segues.

Comment: how do I do that for this certain part only? sorry because I'm new to this

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
var selectedIndex : Int = -1

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.selectedIndex = indexPath.row
    if (selectedIndex == 0 || selectedIndex == 1){
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "submitViewController", sender: nil)
    }else if (selectedIndex == MENU_ACCOUNT_STATISTIC_INDEX){
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let target = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "searchResultViewController") as! SearchResultViewController
        target.resultContent = self.resultContent
        navigationController?.pushViewController(target, animated: true)
    }
}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if let submitViewController: ViewController = segue.destination as! SubmitViewController{
        if (selectedIndex == 0){
            submitViewController.currency = Constant.CURRENCY_MYR
        }else{
            submitViewController.currency = Constant.CURRENCY_SGD
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In my codes do have the func tableView but I not sure how should I change it to be
        
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if (MENU_ACCOUNT_STATISTIC_INDEX == indexPath.row){
            // for account statistic
            searchManager.performSearchAccountStatistic()
        }
    }

Comment: after I made some changes I got this error 
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file /Users/desmondwkh/Downloads/vboss-final/tab88/SearchResultViewController.swift, line 76
2020-04-04 20:28:12.720037+0800 vboss[39539:2111250] Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file /Users/desmondwkh/Downloads/vboss-final/tab88/SearchResultViewController.swift, line 76

Comment: Have you identified SearchResultViewController in storyboard. storyboard -> SearchResultViewController.swift -> Idenitity -> Storyboard Id

Comment: yeah, its SearchResultViewController.

Comment: "SearchResultViewController" and "searchResultViewController" are different things

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved, it was actually due to this part was using the segue from the storyboard that was set for another ViewController. So all I had to do was to change the storyboard setting for that particular segue and it solve for this part as well.